# Emacs speedbar doesn't show all file types such as .bin

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

I found that emacs speedbar does not show all the type of files
Especially, `.bin` files does not show up in my case

I have tried some settings as below, but it still doesn't work
Do you have any idea for this issue or I'm missing something for the setup

setting #1

```sh
(setq sr-speedbar-show-unknown-files t)
(custom-set-variables '(speedbar-show-unknown-files t))
(custom-set-variables '(sr-speedbar-show-unknown-files t))
```

setting #2

```sh
(setq speedbar-add-supported-extension ".bin")
```

setting #3

```sh
(setq speedbar-directory-unshown-regexp "^\(\.\.*$\)\'")
```

Comment: Hi, this questions is offtopic for StackOverflow, you will get better answers at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeap, I should go there, thank you